# start service from activity and wait until its ready

Tags: android, service, asynchronous, android-activity

I want to start a Service from an Activity.

First I tried it with a LocalBinder. This works, but the service was bound to the activity. I don't want to stop the service when the activity is gone. I found no solution with the LocalBinder so I removed it and tried this:

use a singleton instance in the service
call the startService methode in a new thread and waits until the instance is available:

```
final Intent recordService = new Intent(RecordActivity.this, RecordService.class);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startService(recordService);
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();

    Log.i(MMLF.T, "service instance: "+serviceInstance);
    final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
            RecordActivity.this, "Waiting", "wait until record service is loaded",
            true);
    while (serviceInstance == null) {
        serviceInstance = RecordService.get();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(MMLF.T, "could not sleep", e);
        }
    }
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

But this doesn't work, too. It stucked in the waiting loop. If I remove this waiting stuff and the new `new Thread(r).start()` line is the last, the activity and service start fine.

How to start a service independent from an activity? I also let them to communicate with each other. The activity should call two methods (start and stop recording) and the service should send messages. For the second I can use LocalBroadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, because Services already live independently of Activities.  Note, however, that Services run in the main thread by default.  If you want to run the Service in a different thread (and in this case it looks like you do), you will have to set up a Messenger object and send messages between your worker thread and your UI thread.  You can also look into using AIDL (on top of which Messenger is really built anyway).  Your communication, if you don't use a Messenger, could use intents.  If this is the case, you should look into [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).  However, this only works when you are sending messages *to* the Service, not back and forth.  If you want back and forth communication, you will have to use some sort of Messenger or similar pattern.

By the way, using an IntentService for things like 'stop' and 'start' is pretty common.  Typically there is also a background thread, which communicates with the Service using a Messenger or something similar, and then sends / receives messages to instruct the worker thread as to what should be done.

You might also look into AsyncTask, as it makes this kind of thing much simpler.

Comment: I tried an IntentService, but it still not works. Then I switch to an AsyncTask with success. But in my case I figured out, that I don't need an async. execution. The service / AsyncTask should record some sensor data. In debug mode I saw, that ``onSensorChanged()`` method are called by the main / UI thread. My assumption was, that it will not be called by the main thread.